# Django reCAPTCHA does not validate the response

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement Django reCAPTCHA on my forms . The problem is , it does not validate the reCAPTCHA session everytime , I correctly submit the form. I attempted to submit the reCAPTCHA form about 30 times and it still wouldn't validate the reCAPTCHA.

I've implemented the reCAPTCHA on development server, and I added the domain as www.example.com .

I'm also using this tutorial http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/recaptcha_with_django

Can this be the reason why , it won't validate because , I'm using development otherwise can someone please help me ?

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset
from django.shortcuts import render
from recaptcha.client import captcha  


def forgot_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = captcha.submit(request.POST.get('recaptcha_challenge_field'),  request.POST.get('recaptcha_response_field'),  '1231d12dsad12',  request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],)  


        if response.is_valid:
            captcha_response = "YOU ARE HUMAN: %(data)s" % {'data' :  edit_form.data['data_field']}  
        else:  
            captcha_response = 'YOU ARE ROBOT'
            return render(request, 'forgot_password.html',{'captcha_response':captcha_response})



    else:
        return render(request, 'forgot_password.html')
```

template

```
{% block title %}Forgot Password<br>{% endblock title %}


<form method="post" action="{% url accounts:forgot-password %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Please enter your email address.
        You will receive a link to create a new password via email.</p>

    <input type="email" name="email"
        placeholder="Your e-mail"><br/>



        <th>Are you human?</th>  

            <span class="validation_error">{{ captcha_response }}</span>  

            <script type="text/javascript"  
            src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=123dwqsdasd123e23d32d32">  
            </script>  

            <noscript>  
            <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=123dwqsdasd123e23d32d32">  
            height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>  
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">  
            </textarea>  
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"   
            value="manual_challenge">  
            </noscript>  


                 <button type="submit">Send new password</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Try to make your reCaptcha key Global if you didn't done it already.

Comment: @Piotr Jaszkowski Can you please explain lil abit more about making the key global

Comment: ahh sorry you cannot change key to be global. But you can create new one with global option enabled on this site: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Comment: why are you accessing it as an iframe ? It can be a simple form field

Comment: @karthikr oh the tutorial says to access it via iframe

Answer (score 2):

You could do your own implementation:

```
import urllib, urllib2, re

def recaptcha(request, postdata):
        rc_challenge = postdata.get('recaptcha_challenge_field','')
        rc_user_input = postdata.get('recaptcha_response_field', '').encode('utf-8')
        url = 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify'
        values = {'privatekey' : 'PRIVATE-KEY', 'remoteip': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'challenge' : rc_challenge, 'response' : rc_user_input,}
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        answer = response.read().split()[0]
        response.close()
        return answer
```

This returns true when captcha was typed right else false.

In your view you could then do something like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    captcha = recaptcha(request, postdata)
    if captcha:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something else
```

You would have to adjust your template a bit, should not be to hard to figure it out. Hope this leads into the right direction.

Comment: Can I ask , what adjust do I need to make ? I'm been learning django for only few months :(

Comment: hmm, maybe it works like you already got it. {{ captcha_response }} should be rendered from your view as I see. Also you may change the javascript to point to the google api('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=PUBLIC-KEY"></script>')Just give it a try and look how far it gets you.

Comment: Let me know, when things go wrong, I implemented the captcha this way succesfully on several sites. I havent implemented something when there is no response from google-api-servers, so you would have to do that on your own.

Comment: i have no idea why it doesn't work . Maybe it's because i'm using it on development

Answer (score 0):

There is [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha) it would be simply and clearly